# jQuery Tree Menu collapsing wrong way

Tags: jquery, html

just one quick question about jQuery. I pretty new to this...

If I click on Submenu the list should slide down and every other open one should slide up. So far it's working. But when I click on the open one, it slides up and down again. How can I stop the open one from doing that? The open should just stay there when it's clicked...

Thanks very much!

```
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"></a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">S</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.treeview ul li a').click(function(ev) {
                $('.treeview .sub-menu').not($(this).parents('.sub-menu')).slideUp();
                $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideDown();
                ev.preventDefault();
            });
```

Comment: Creating a jsFiddle reproducing your issue is a good idea

Comment: `<script>` tags would help

Comment: $(this).parents('.sub-menu') should be $(this).next('.sub-menu') right?

Comment: +1 for providing *just* enough code and HTML to reproduce :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your `not` selector was not getting any matches, so nothing was excluded.

With trees, you want to use selectors that operate relative to the item clicked. Then they can work for nested elements too.

Try this one:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/EnJ68/1/

```
$('.treeview ul li a').click(function (ev) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Collapse all other lists under parent list
    $this.closest('li').siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
    // Expand the sibling lists
    $this.siblings().slideDown();
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

You will notice it now handles child menus the same way as the parent.

*note: you will also want to start everything in a collapsed state. so have this as well:

```
$('.treeview>ul>li>ul').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. That was helping a lot!